# TestFlight Beta Testing

Tags: delphi, app-store-connect, firemonkey, testflight, delphi-xe7

When I upload my App over Application Loader to iTunes Connect it say

> To use TestFlight Beta Testing, build 0.9.10 must contain the correct beta entitlement.

In my mobileprovision profile I have

```xml
<key>get-task-allow</key>
<false/>
<key>beta-reports-active</key>
<true/>
```

but it has no effect.

Any idea how to solve it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution:

In your project folder is file **Entitlement.TemplateiOS.xml**
add this code and recompile application

```
<key>get-task-allow</key>
<false/>
<key>beta-reports-active</key>
<true/>
```

If you edit file C:\Users\%YOU_USER_NAME%\AppData\Roaming\Embarcadero\BDS\15.0\Entitlement.TemplateiOS.xml then in new projects code will be present